# unexpected resize of fixed textarea in chrome using polymer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, polymer

I've got a problem with a textarea, that should permanently fill the whole page. Therefore, I use polymer layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/src/polymer/layout.html">
</head>
<body unresolved fullbleed horizontal layout>
  <textarea flex self-stretch id="myTextarea" style="resize: none; background-color: lightgray"></textarea>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var textarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
    textarea.value = 'something';
    setTimeout(function () {
      textarea.value = 'another\nrow';
    }, 5000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I created [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kxdamf31/2/) JSFiddle as desired.

It works in Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox 30, but in Chrome 35 my textarea changes its height, if its content is changed with javascript to a content with a different row count. Why does this happen? How can I solve this?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I created a fiddle (see edit). I hope someone can help me now.